# Get full path from <a href ="/..."> and <a href = "..">

Tags: html, href

From parsing several websites, it seems that with a "/" in the beginning of the link, it points to a different location than without. For example,
URL = "http://www.google.com/a/b/c/index.html"
     `<a href = "/location1.html">` will link to "http://www.google.com/location1.html", essentially (domain+link). And
`<a href = "location2.html">` will link to "http://www.google.com/a/b/c/location2.html".

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Why downvoting without comments???

Comment: Pretty much a dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls/21828923#21828923

Answer (score 0):

Those are relative paths:

if your domain name was http://google.com

Then you could do:

```
/location1.html
```

or

```
/location2.html
```

and that would point to: http://google.com/location1.html

but since you probably don't own that domain in order to link to google.com you need to include an absolute path:

```
http://www.google.com/a/b/c/location1.html
```

Comment: I took google.com for example. I own the domain. You can try this example in your own browser. <html>
<a href="/location1.html">href1</a>
<a href="location2.html">href2</a>
</html>

Comment: Oh ok. So basically you can do /location1.html and it will point to http://yourdomain/location1.html . Hope that helps.